# call a RegFree COM vb6 dll with ocx dependencies from Excel

Tags: vba, regfreecom

I used MMM to generate a manifest file to call a VB6 DLL with OCX dependencies via a VB6.exe client and this works fine Reg-Free on the target machine.

an extract of the manifest file is as per below, which shows the VB6 MS Chart control  dependency (MSCHRT20.ocx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <!-- Make My Manifest 0.9.305 -->
  <assemblyIdentity name="DLL_Tester" processorArchitecture="X86" type="win32" version="1.0.0.0" />

  <file name="TankChecker3_DLL.dll">
    <typelib tlbid="{A23FD5EC-6750-4454-8417-A53FB6436646}" version="14.0" flags="" helpdir="" />
    <comClass clsid="{265A4F7E-3380-41F9-B3D2-624D0B9DD0FA}" tlbid="{A23FD5EC-6750-4454-8417-A53FB6436646}" progid="TankChecker3_DLL.CChart" description="" />
  </file>
  <file name="MSCHRT20.OCX">
    <typelib tlbid="{65E121D4-0C60-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}" version="2.0" flags="control" helpdir="" />
    <comClass clsid="{3A2B370C-BA0A-11D1-B137-0000F8753F5D}" tlbid="{65E121D4-0C60-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}" progid="MSChart20Lib.MSChart.2" description="Microsoft Chart Control 6.0 (OLEDB)" />
  </file>

:
: etc
:

</assembly>
```

I want to make this work Reg-Free with Excel, using the Windows.ActCtx object in Windows 7. If I just use a simple test HelloWorld VB6 dll with no .ocx dependencies, this works fine in Excel 2010 on the target machine

see below for the test manifest file I used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <!-- Make My Manifest 0.9.305 -->
  <assemblyIdentity name="SideBySide2Client" processorArchitecture="X86" type="win32" version="1.0.0.0" />

  <file name="SideBySide2.dll">
    <typelib tlbid="{DD83DC2F-C5C0-40F2-B2F4-B7310B098A16}" version="6.0" flags="" helpdir="" />
    <comClass clsid="{EDF044DE-A6EF-4FE9-9446-67384C1CA8E4}" tlbid="{DD83DC2F-C5C0-40F2-B2F4-B7310B098A16}" threadingModel="Apartment" progid="SideBySide2.SideBySideClass" description="" />
  </file>
</assembly>
```

However if I try the same technique with the full dll with the ocx dependencies, it give error code 339 (can't find the ocx dependency) on the target machine

All files are just in the one folder for XCOPY deployment.

To sum up,  it works fine with the VB6 client but not in the VBA / ActCtx client. 
Any ideas why this doesn't work?

thanks David

Answer (score 0):

This is a licensed control supplied as part of VB 6.0 and other development tools.

You cannot just glom onto it and use it from applications like Excel.  As far as I can tell this is even true when you have Office Developer Edition, VSTA/VSTO, etc.

That may not be the only problem, but since this library is not redistributable except as part of a VB 6.0, etc. application there is little point.